# attr_accessor and class instance debug

Tags: ruby-on-rails, attributes

I don't understand why if I write:

```
class Building < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessor :has_child_custom, 'test'
end
```

and then I try to debug it with

```
 ap @building
```

I don't see "has_child_custom", but if I type:

```
 ap @building.public_methods.grep(/custom/)
```

I see getter and setter methods.

Why does it happen and where I can see my custom attribute?

Answer (score 0):

Your code creates accessor methods for getting and setting  an instance variable  called `@has_child_custom`. That instance variable won't actually exist though until you call the setter method (or otherwise create it).

You're also creating accessor methods `test` and `test=`

Comment: but how can I set a default value?

Comment: I'd use one of the activerecord lifecycle callbacks.

Comment: Thx a lot, and what should I do if just need to print all attributes and methods of model or class if I need to get whole view?

Answer (score 0):

I would be very careful using getter and setter functions in ActiveRecord objects. Those will overwrite methods that are already built in for you by ActiveRecord and things can get very confusing.

If you want to initialize values or set defaults in an ActiveRecord object, the best thing to do is use [ActiveRecord callbacks](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html).

Usually, when I want to initialize values, do I something to this effect:

```
def initialize(*args)
  self.attribute_to_initialize = *something here*
end
```

Comment: Thx a lot, and what should I do if just need to print all attributes and methods of model or class if I need to get whole view?